# Audio file encode base64 Android

Tags: android, base64

I have a question, how can I send my audio file to my server, I had tried to convert to base64 but nothing is working. This is my code

declaration of variables:

```
private MediaRecorder grabacion;
private String archivoSalida = null;
```

audio obtained with media record:

```
archivoSalida = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Myrecord.mp3";
        grabacion = new MediaRecorder();
        grabacion.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        grabacion.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        grabacion.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        grabacion.setOutputFile(archivoSalida);
```

Convert to base64,the error comes out here:

```
private String convertirAudString(MediaRecorder audio){
   ByteArrayOutputStream array=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] audioByte = new byte[(int)audio.length()];//error in this line

    String audioString = Base64.encodeToString(audioByte,Base64.DEFAULT);

    return audioString;
}
```

Comment: you send your audio file through multi part request to your server??? because in multipart request you don't need to convert into base64 encoded.

Comment: Not yet, how could I send it? I'm thinking of sending it with volley ... and sending images works fine with base64

Comment: oh you wrote you are sending audio files. but now you are saying images. !!! update your question

Comment: try this Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes)

Comment: @unzila: I meant that sending images works for me, mi app send images and audio...and I think was the same but not

Comment: got it u try this Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes)

Comment: excuse me for not specifying it from the beginning

Comment: its ok no problem:)

Comment: @unzila ...this Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes); it does not work!

Comment: paste your logcat in your question plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your all suggestion.
I solve this, with using
`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Miaudio.mp3");
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);`

Then I convert it to base64; it works for me very fast.